# How did Rand light the pipe without channeling?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In the final Wheel of Time book, "Memory of Light", protagonist Rand Al'Thor

> survives the Last Battle by switching bodies with Moridin.

Afterwards, he finds that he cannot channel, yet somehow lights his pipe.

> By instinct, he reached for the One Power to light it. He found
>   nothing. No *saidin* in the void, nothing. He paused, then smiled and
>   felt an enormous relief. He could not channel. Just to be certain, he
>   tentatively reached for the True Power. Nothing there either.
>
> He regarded his pipe, riding up a little incline to the side of Thakan'dar, now covered in plants. No way to light the tabac. He inspected it
>   for a moment in the darkness, then *thought* of the pipe being lit. And
>   it was.

This event is not explained further - it just happens and he thinks of it as "impossible" before smiling and going about his business. It does seem very similar to how things work in Tel'aran'rhiod, though, with thoughts manifesting as reality.

**How did he light the pipe without using either *saidin* or the True Power? Has Brandon Sanderson or anyone else explained this action?**

Answer (score 5):

I believe that we simply don't know.  To quote the [Tor website](https://www.tor.com/2013/01/23/brandon-sandersons-wheel-of-time-answers-from-torchat/):

> Not even Brandon knows what’s going with Rand’s pipe-lighting at the end of A Memory of Light. “I put it in as RJ instructed, and I know nothing more about it than fandom does, I’m afraid.”

Personal opinion: he had been essentially in charge of creation, altering it at will.  Some left-over bit of that could let him light it.

Comment: I took it to mean that he came to understand that the "real" world is merely a construct like the dream world and could influence it as such.